# How to create a stub?

Tags: java, stub

I am trying to create a stub of `Customer` which from my knowledge is a fake class as `myCustomer` cannot be resolved to this. However, I have checked everywhere online on any basic tutorial or examples to create a stub but cannot find it anywhere.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Bank {
    public int bankAccount(int customerNumber, int startingBalance){

    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome Everyone.");
        Customer myCustomer = Customer.getWithCustomerNumber(customerNumber);
        String name = myCustomer.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to actually write the customer class and invoke with some form of a constructor. You can stub out classes with stubbed methods or no methods at all, but to my knowledge this cannot be done programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My IDE (NetBeans) automatically created a stubbed `Customer` like this:

```
private static class Customer {

    private String name;

    private static Customer getWithCustomerNumber(int customerNumber) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public Customer() {
    }
}
```